# Pandas Restrict Series to last Row Not Containing Blank Cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks at specific business metrics on a daily basis for the current year. In my csv I have a date column with dates from the first of the year to the last and additional columns for the metrics being analyzed. While the date column has values for the complete year, the metrics columns have blank cells for each day after the current date within the current year. For my analysis, I only want to analyze the data set up to the last value that is not blank for the metrics columns. I thought I could achieve this by replacing "blank" with `np.nan` and then filtering my series by only those that are  numbers, but I don't think this is the right approach as I receive an error. Is there a better method?

Current Attempt with Error:

```
df_raw = df_raw.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
print(df_raw.tail())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tail'
```

Here is what my data looks like:

```
    date    |    cost    |    impression    |   ...
2 2018-01-01  $209492.29     14,9232
3 2018-01-02  $3248492.29     482,293
....
365 2018-12-30       
366 2018-12-31
```

Code:

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_values(),columns=sheet.get_all_values()[1])

# exclude header(s) from row count NEEDS TO BE UPDATED BASED ON DATA SET
df_raw = df_raw.drop(df_raw.index[[0,1]])

# convert date column to datetime format
df_raw['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_raw['date'])

# convert blank rows with nan
df_raw = df_raw.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
print(df_raw.tail())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the data...

If you already converted all the blanks to np.nan and you know that the metrics field will always have a value if it's before the current date then you could run...

```
df = df.dropna() #Drop all rows containing nan  

#or you could run

df.dropna(thresh=2)   #Drop row if it does not have at least two values that are **not** NaN
```

Comment: Right methods that I was looking for. Completely slipped my mind

Answer (score 1):

`inplace` is supposed to do the replacement without needing the additional `df_raw =`. Note that the docs say "Returns the caller if this is True." for this param. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

I suspect that this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up that confusion. Makes sense